How can I make my app read 20,000 documents uploaded to Firebase quickly?
I created a quiz app that involves reading about 20,000 documents from Firebase (with other fields inside) where there are names that need to be searched through a search bar in various activities of the app. I tried to create a main activity (which is executed as soon as the app starts) that would allow me to load and save all these documents in the device's cache the first time, so that subsequently it would not have to reload all these documents from scratch. Doing this with about 3,000 documents worked, but now the app can no longer handle it and crashes because the cache memory capacity is not sufficient.
This is the activity I tried to implement, I also tried to set a limit of 20,000 documents, but it still doesn't work.
https://gist.github.com/quizballinfo/38d5f7a25d2d1256b65da7088ee1460b
https://gist.github.com/quizballinfo/38d5f7a25d2d1256b65da7088ee1460b
I would like to create a more efficient method to load all the documents only the first time, so that it starts more quickly the subsequent times.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

I post a link with the code

A question should not relay on external resources. If that link disappears in the future, than this question is useless. Please add the (relevant) part of the code inside the question

The question is a bit unclear. Why do you need to read 20,000 documents at one time? Along with @alexmamo answer, 20,000 may not actually be "too much" data; it depends on what is contained within each document e.g. 20,000 docs containing only person names (30 bytes per = 60k + overhead) isn't very demanding. Denormalizing the data is one option. If this is a query why not query the docs to return a subset of data? Questions should generally include the code you've attempted and not links How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Hi @Jay ,thank you for your response. Yes, I probably explain myself poorly (unfortunately, I don't speak English well and I apologize for that). I don't need to read 20,000 documents at the same time, but they belong to a sort of large database made up of celebrity names that are used in my quizzes. In summary, the user, depending on the challenge they have to complete, needs to search for the name of the celebrity that is included in the fields of the various documents present in this large collection
Example: Document"Cristiano Ronaldo"-Field: Name "Cristiano Ronaldo", Team: "Real Madrid".

That sounds like you need to query your Firestore for the celebrity name. Firebase is fast and scalable so 100,000 documents containing celebrity names and a team name is really not a 'large database' and a query would return results almost instantly. In fact scaling that up to 1,000,000 still responds almost instantly (I've tested that many times!). So it's not clear what the actual trouble is; if you're concerned about query performance, don't be - Firestore can handle that easily.

The main problem I am encountering is that to open the activity where this collection with all these documents (with their fields inside) is used, it takes too much time. While before, when it had to load about 3000 documents, it took about 20 seconds (which was already too much time in my opinion), now with 20000 you understand that the time becomes too long. That's why I was looking for a system to download this collection to the device first and save it somewhere to then use it more smoothly in subsequent times.

Perhaps there's a language barrier here but Firebase doesn't have "activities" and you don't need to "open" anything. To retrieve a set of documents, execute a query and the results will be returned quickly. Per above you don't even need to get 20,000 results so the response should be almost instantaneous. If it's not, there's a coding issue but we won't be able to assist with that as the question doesn't include your code. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example


Doing this with about 3,000 documents worked, but now the app can no longer handle it and crashes because the cache memory capacity is not sufficient.

That's the expected behavior. Reading 3k documents at once can be considered an incredibly large amount of data.

This is the activity I tried to implement, I also tried to set a limit of 20,000 documents, but it still doesn't work.

If you get a crash when you read 3k documents, then you'll never be able to read 20k documents.

I would like to create a more efficient method to load all the documents only the first time.

There is no way you can load such a large amount of data because it will never fit into the memory.

I created a quiz app that involves reading about 20,000 documents from Firebase (with other fields inside) where there are names that need to be searched through a search bar in various activities of the app.

If you need to download all the documents so you can create a search feature, then I recommend you use one of the following options.
The first solution would be to implement a third-party library that does the search for you. It can be Algolia, Elastic Search or Typesense. If you don't want to implement that yourself then you can use the corresponding Firebase Extensions:

Search Firestore with Algolia
Search with Elastic App Search
Search Firestore with Typesense

If you don't want to implement a third-party library, then I recommend you denormalize the data and store only the names that you want to search in, into a single document. If those names don't fit into a single document due to the 1 MiB limitation, then store the names into multiple documents. In this way, you'll always download only the necessary data that you want to search in and nothing more.

First of all, thank you for the response. But with Algolia, besides searching for the document name, does it allow me to also read its related fields in the activity? Let me explain better, for example within the name of a celebrity, there are various fields that are needed for the logic of my quizzes. So does Algolia, in addition to optimizing the search, allow me to read all the fields within the documents?

If you add multiple fields inside Algolia, index, yes.

Thank you for your availability. I wanted to try creating a bundle in txt that encompasses the entire collection. I am having difficulty giving the device permission to download this bundle via a URL (even though I have indicated the permissions in the manifest). I will try to open a new thread.

Yes, if you have difficulty implementing the bundle mechanism, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, so I or other Firebase developers can help you.

So did my answer/comments help? Can I help you with other information?
